# Tcp Socket Closed

Tags: tcp, sockets

I always thought that if you didn't implement a heartbeat, there was no way to know if one side of a TCP connection died unexpectedly.  If the process was just killed on one side and didn't exit gracefully, there was no way for the socket to send FIN or let the other side know that it was closed.

(See some of the comments here for example http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=566568 )

But there is a stock order server that I connect to that has a new "cancel all orders on disconnect feature" that cancels live orders if the client dis-connects.  It works even when I kill the process on my end, and there is definitely no heartbeat from my app to it.

So how is it able to detect when I've killed the process?  My app is running on Windows Server 2003 and the order server is on Suse Linux Enterprise Server 10.  Does Windows detect that the process associated with the socket is no longer alive and send the FIN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a process exits - for whatever reason - the OS will close the TCP connections it had open.

There's numerous other ways a TCP connection can go dead undetected

- someone yanks out a network cable inbetween.
- the computer at the other end gets nuked.
- a nat gateway inbetween silently drops the connection
- the OS at the other end crashes hard.
- the FIN packets gets lost.

Though enabling tcp keepalive, you'll detect it eventually - atleast during a couple of hours.

Comment: Btw can you elaborate abit more on how "the FIN packets gets lost"?

Comment: @Pacerier Well, IP is unreliable, there's a number of ways packets get dropped or damaged. If the FIN packet (and subsequent FIN retransmissions or RST packets), which is supposed to conwey to the peer that the connection should be closed, is lost, the peer will never know about that fact. Perhaps the peer is expecting to receive more data which will never happen.

Comment: Yes I mean what about the "number of ways packets get dropped or damaged"?

Comment: @Pacerier If an ethernet switch the packet travels through is out of buffer space, it drops packets. Same with routers. Same even for the sending and receiving host, they drop packets when there's no more buffer space. Packets can of course also be damaged in transit, cables arn't perfect, transmission interference happens, resulting in bit errors.

Comment: @nos Regarding the FIN packets gets lost. If the sending FIN packet is lost the ACK will not be received and then the FIN will be re-transmitted so this will be detected?

Comment: @croraf That FIN packet can get lost too. And the next one can get lost. You probably think that is so rare it can never happen. But it will. Someone can alter routing inbetween the client/server so packets never get through anymore. The connection can be so congested, that packets are dropped constantly etc.

Comment: @nos Thanks, I was thinking about that. I was wondering why you put that as a specific case in the list (it is the same case as if any other TCP message is lost due to the bullet 1, 3 or any of the reasons you mentioned in one of your previous comments).  I think it would be clearer if that bullet was instead: "nodes inbetween get congested" and "links inbetween get damaged or malfunctioning" (the last one being the same as bullet 1)?

Answer (score 2):

It could be using a TCP Keep Alive to check for dead peers:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the OS detects the process termination and closes all the file descriptors/sockets/handles the process was using. So, there isn't difference between "killing" application and "gracefully terminating". Of course, the kernel itself must be running (=pc turned on, wire connected...). But it's on the OS the job of sending the FIN and so on...
Also, if a host becomes unreachable /turned off, disconnected...) an intermediate gateway (or the client itself) may detect the event (e.g. loss of carrier, DHCP lease not renewed...) and reply to the packets sent to the died host with a ICMP error (host/network unreachable). This causes the peer's TCP connection to die, but it happens only if the client has some packet to send to the host.