# Android socket not closed after network change, no duplicate

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm using a socket for android <---> server communication. When I establish the connection with WIFI and then turn off WIFI the phone switches to cellular data. Obviously the socket can no longer be used. However I can not find a way to check if the socket is no longer usable.

`socket.isConnected()` true

`socket.isClosed()` false

`socket.write()` returns without an exception. That's why this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811653/what-happened-to-socket-if-network-has-broken-down)

`socket.read()` blocking, not returning -1 or any exceptions

`socket.isOutputShutdown()` false

Implementing a heartbeat behavior myself would be viable but it looks like there should be a way to see if the socket is invalid. A read timeout is not reasonable in my case since the time between reading data can vary.

Comment: I am not all that familiar with Android Networking. The idea that comes to mind is to listen for a system notification when the wifi is turned off.

Comment: I thought about that but it seems like a (ugly) workaround since network access can be aquired via wifi / cellular / bluetooth / maybe even usb which would be hard to cover all of them?

Comment: Do you interrupt the "socket-dedicated" thread when wi-fi is off?

Comment: Currently I'm not checking if wifi is changing. Isn't there a solution by using the socket? Since this solution would require me to listen for wifi / cellular / bluetooth / usb? changes

Comment: You can also vary the read timeout per read, but you need to understand that it is the maximum time the read will block, not the total time for the read, so maybe you don't need to.