# want to change TCP closing timeout

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

We have a client server application in use on our suse linux server.
Sometimes it happens, that on the client side the tcp socket somehow goes away and
on the server side the other end of the socket remains existent.

At the end of the day, when we stop the backend on the linux server, the backend tries to close all remaining tcp connections, also those "zombie" sockets.

(I watch this with strace).

When the backend tries to close a tcp connection, where there is nothing anymore on the client side, it sends a [FIN, ACK] packet to the target. And of course, nothing comes back.

The backend repeats to send this packet. The first time it waits only a few hundredths of a second to repeat it, then, it waits longer and longer. At the end it waits seconds to repeat it. But, after 15 seconds, there is a timeout, and it goes on to end another 
tcp connection.

Now, I do not know where this 15 second timeout is coming from. I would like to change it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I suggest you fix the two *bugs* you describe, instead of probably introducing more with new code. 1. Sockets do not just 'go away'. They get closed, or they leak from the application. A socket leak is a major problem and must be addressed. 2. A TCP application can always detect a disconnection by the peer, one way or the other. If your application doesn't do that it is incorrectly written and again must be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have two problems.

- You should detect the client disconnecting and close the server's end of the socket so you free that resources ASAP. You may set a timeout yourself for connections with no activity in the application layer. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428804/tcp-socket-closed?rq=1).
- If you cannot handle that "zombie" sockets in the app layer you may change the timeout in the SO. Read [this](http://fixunix.com/tcp-ip/555894-question-about-tcp-retransmission-timeout.html).